# Message box with Show Details Option?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-3.5

I need to show a MessageBox with the Show Details option , like what we get during normal windows exceptions. When the user clicks the show details option, it has to expand and show the collection of details to the user. How to achieve it in Windows forms?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just create a new WinForm with that features , what is the question?

Comment: there are a million components that do this for you. They use the task dialog api on vista and above and an emulated version on XP. Just search for .net task dialog.

Comment: Look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40469355/3314922). It contains the implementation I used.

Answer (score 1):

These dialogs are not exposed as part of any API and so you need to create your own dialog that behaves the same way.

A dialog is simply a standard form shown using the `ShowDialog` method:

```
DetailsMessageBox dialog = new DetailsMessageBox();
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // Handle me
}
```

Before your dialog closes you should set the `DialogResult` property of the form is set to the desired dialog outcome - you can get buttons to automatically set the dialoig result (and close the dialog) for you when they are clicked by setting the `DialogResult` property of the button to the desired result.

You should also set the `AcceptButton` and `CancelButton` properties of your dialog to suitable buttons so that the dialog is closed when the use presses Escape or Enter.

Answer (score 0):

These types of forms are only via API available on Windows Vista and higher. You'd best just create your own form. That way you can make it precisely how you want it :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to make your own messagebox. You can then add as much additional functionality as you'd like, including event/error logging etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `TaskDialog` API, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787471(v=vs.85).aspx