# How to make an error messagebox that contains a button to show error details?

Tags: c#, messagebox, .net-framework-version

I want to use C# to make an error messagebox with an option to show details of the error just like the messagebox below:

[image]

Does anybody know how to make a messagebox like that?

Comment: You would need to make it manually

Comment: I really don't have any idea how. @MatthewFrontino

Comment: Look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40469355/3314922). It contains the implementation I used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, the dialog is not intended to be used directly:

[ThreadExceptionDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.threadexceptiondialog(v=vs.100).aspx)

However, it looks to me like you can use it like a standard dialog:

```
try {
    // code
}
catch(Exception e) {
    var d = new ThreadExceptionDialog(e);
    d.ShowDialog();
}
```

If they hit continue I imagine you will drop out of ShowDialog and continue.  If they press Quit I imagine execution stops.  Easy to test.

Of course it would only be a fairly easy job to put together your own version to use as you please and you would have total control over it.

Comment: Thanks for this information. This is very useful. But how will I call the ThreadExceptionDialog when an exception occured? I tried to find reference on how to do that but I can't find any. . .

Comment: Added what I assume is a viable example.

Comment: Successfully made one. :) Thanks a lot. . .